# Ho to use string concatenation in an http-block in Inspec?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, inspec

I've got an Inspec-control containing a http-block. The URL is saved in a variable called `DNScloudui['value']` - I want to add `https://` to the beginning of the URL.

```
DNScloudui = attribute('DNS_name_cloudui')

control 'Website reachability' do
  title 'Check reachability by GET requests'
  describe http(DNScloudui['value'], method: 'GET') do
    its('status') { should cmp 200 }
  end
end
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Doesn't an interpolation like `"https//#{DNScloudui['value']}"` work?

Comment: nope (unterminated regexp meets end of file (SyntaxError))

Comment: What's the value of `DNScloudui`?

Comment: Alternatively `DNScloudui = "https://#{attribute('DNS_name_cloudui')}"`, and if that does not work then the above comment is definitely relevant.

Comment: the value of DNScloudui is something of this form:
"foo.bar.foo-bar.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that `DNScloudui` returns you a non-nil value, then you can use string interpolation to get the value of the `DNScloudui` variable. for instance:

```
DNScloudui = attribute('DNS_name_cloudui')

control 'Website reachability' do
  title 'Check reachability by GET requests'
  describe http("https://#{DNScloudui['value']}", method: 'GET') do
    its('status') { should cmp 200 }
  end
end
```

also, looking at the name of your `DNScloudui` variable, i would suggest to stick to [ruby naming conventions and style guides](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide)